# LINQPad and Oracle

Tags: oracle, linqpad

Does LINQPad work with Oracle?  Has anyone tried?  What do you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by their [user voice item request for Oracle support](http://linqpad.uservoice.com/pages/18302-linqpad-feature-suggestions/suggestions/189591-support-oracle-mysql-sqlite-databases?ref=title), it appears unsupported at the moment.

A [comment on the O'Reilly forums](http://forums.oreilly.com/content/C-3-0-in-a-Nutshell/322/Linqpad-On-Other-Databasetypes/#entry2208) also suggests its not supported.

**update** As we understand it, there's now built-in Oracle support in the latest versions of LinqPad; the home page of LinqPad now lists support for Oracle.

**update January 2013** The new LinqPad-to-Oracle support appears to still be available. Per the [LinqPad FAQ](http://www.linqpad.net/FAQ.aspx):

> Q. Why does LINQPad use LINQ to SQL under the covers, rather than Entity Framework?
>
> A. LINQ to SQL is faster with large schemas and in most cases, emits
>   better SQL. You can, however, use EF with EDMs that you define
>   yourself. For querying SQLite, MySQL and Oracle (via the optional
>   plug-in), LINQPad uses Matt Warren's IQueryable toolkit.

Answer (score 10):

As of [beta](http://linqpad.net/Beta.aspx) version 4.35, LINQPad supports Oracle fully - you can now do "LINQ to Oracle" queries. I believe it uses the [DevArt dotConnect](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) libraries for managing this great feat. Further, in addition to native OCI support, it also supports a direct mode which does not require the Oracle OCI DLLs to be present.

To enable this feature you will need to simply add a new data connection in LINQPad, and when asked which driver to use - click the `View more drivers...` button. You can then install the IQ Driver and use it for querying Oracle, MySQL and SQLite databases.

[image: IQ Connection Options showing Oracle, MySQL and SQLite support]

Answer (score 2):

Linqpad now has support for lightspeed which supports oracle.