# How can I use LinqPad's generated context in Visual Studio

Tags: linqpad, devart

This is a follow-on from this question really:

[Moving From LINQpad to a Proper Visual Studio Project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140385/moving-from-linqpad-to-a-proper-visual-studio-project)

..but I'm not able to get it to work properly.

An answer to that question suggestions dumping the context assembly out as a dll but although I have done that, when I import it as a reference, it's not exactly clear to me how I would create an instance of that context, point it at a database and actually run a query against it, something like the following:

var db = new ContextFromThatDLL(myconnectionstring);

var query = from a in db.MYTABLE where a.ID == 1 select a;

---

Extra information:

I am using the IQ driver in LinqPad to connect to Oracle.

I *do* have a license for DevArt already (which the IQ driver uses) but am aware that the IQ driver generates its own SQL from LINQ - and I prefer it. Plus, I develop queries in LinqPad which works great for my workflow but find that DevArt doesn't always generate SQL as good as IQ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, extract the typed data context in LINQPad as follows:

```
string dcPath = GetType().BaseType.Assembly.Location;
string targetFolder = @"c:\temp";
File.Copy (dcPath, Path.Combine (targetFolder, Path.GetFileName (dcPath)));
```

Then in Visual Studio, reference the typed data context DLL, along with the following DLLs from the driver folder:

- IQDriver.dll
- IQToolkit.dll
- IQToolkit.Data.dll
- IQToolkit.Data.(provider).dll

plus the DevArt driver.

Then, you can instantiate the typed data context as follows (this illustrates how to do it for SQLite):

```
var dc = new LINQPad.User.TypedDataContext (IQToolkit.Data.DbEntityProvider.From
   ("IQToolkit.Data.Sqlite", @"Data Source=D:\SQLite.NET\nutshell.db",
    "LINQPad.User.TypedDataContext"));

var customerCount = dc.Customers.Count();
```

This should get you started. Bear in mind the caveats, as stated in the answer to which you linked!